# editGridRow method works fine, except when the RowId is 0. jqGrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, jqgrid-formatter

I'm fairly new to jqGrid which seems like a great thing. there's lots of documentation which is great.
I'm having a difficulty with editing. I have a grid with multiple rows, and i can't edit all of the rows except for the first one, there is some problem with the method 'editGridRow' when the Row ID is 0. When the Row Id is other, it works fine. Other methods like 'getCell' are working ok, even when the Row id = 0.

How can i solve this?

thanks for the help.

```
$("#grid").jqGrid({
                altRows: true,
                datatype: 'local',
                direction: 'rtl',
                height: '100%',
                mtype: 'POST',
                hidegrid: false,
                colNames: ['מספר הקלסר', 'שם השולח', 'מעגל', 'נושא ראשי', 'הגוף המשלם', 'מספר ארגז', 'תאריך שליחה', 'תאריך התחלה', 'תאריך סיום', 'תאריך גריסה', ''],
                colModel: [
                          { name: 'idFolders', index: 'idFolders', align: 'center', sorttype: 'int' },
                          { name: 'SenderName', index: 'SenderName', align: 'center', editable: true },
                          { name: 'Maagal', index: 'Maagal', align: 'center', editable: true },
                          { name: 'MainSubject', index: 'MainSubject', align: 'center', editable: true },
                          { name: 'PayerName', index: 'PayerName', align: 'center', editable: true },
                          { name: 'BoxNumber', index: 'BoxNumber', align: 'center', sorttype: 'int', editable: true },
                          { name: 'SentDate', index: 'SentDate', align: 'center', sorttype: 'date', datefmt: 'd,m,y', editable: true },
                          { name: 'FolderStartDate', index: 'FolderStartDate', align: 'center', sorttype: 'date', datefmt: 'd,m,y', editable: true },
                          { name: 'FolderEndDate', index: 'FolderEndDate', align: 'center', sorttype: 'date', datefmt: 'd,m,y', editable: true },
                          { name: 'TrashDate', index: 'TrashDate', align: 'center', sorttype: 'date', datefmt: 'd,m,y', editable: true },
                //A column for Buttons - edit, delete, with custom Formatter - "formattEdit"
                          {name: 'myac', align: 'right', sortable: false, resize: false, formatter: formattEdit }
                        ],
                pager: '#pager',
                rowNum: 10,
                rowList: [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 100],
                sortname: 'idFolders',
                sortorder: 'asc',
                viewrecords: true,
                gridview: true,
                caption: 'תוצאות החיפוש', 
                editurl: 'SearchWebService.asmx/editFoldersTable',
                .......
```

the main Grid

```
//formattEdit, creating 2 buttons - Del, Editform.
            function formattEdit(cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
                var del, edit, HoverString, htmlString = "";
                var rowid = options.rowId;
                //Creating the Commands in a Long String
                //Edit
                edit = "onclick=$('#grid').jqGrid('editGridRow'," + rowid + ",{editData:{idFolders:$('#grid').jqGrid('getCell'," + rowid + ",'idFolders')}});";
                HoverString = " onmouseover=jQuery(this).addClass('ui-state-hover'); onmouseout=jQuery(this).removeClass('ui-state-hover');"                
                edit = edit + HoverString;
                htmlString = htmlString + "<div title='" + $.jgrid.nav.edittitle + "' style='float:right;cursor:pointer;' class='ui-pg-div ui-inline-edit' " + edit + "><span class='ui-icon ui-icon-pencil'></span></div>";

                //Delete
                del = "onclick=alert('Deleteing');";
                del = del + HoverString;
                htmlString = htmlString + "<div title='" + $.jgrid.nav.deltitle + "' style='float:right;margin-right:5px;' class='ui-pg-div ui-inline-del' " + del + "><span class='ui-icon ui-icon-trash'></span></div>";

                //Adding it as Html                
                return "<div style='align:center;'>" + htmlString + "</div>";

            }
```

My Custom Formatter - in there is the Call for the 'editGridRow' Method

```
//Search Button - Ajax Call
            $("#searchBtn").click(function () {
                if ($("#searchBox").val() == "") {
                    alert("נא הקלד חיפוש");
                }
                else {
                    var grid = $("#grid")
                    grid.jqGrid("clearGridData", true).trigger("reloadGrid");
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        url: 'SearchWebService.asmx/getTablejQgrid',
                        data: CreateSearchString(),
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function (data, textStatus) {
                            if (textStatus == "success") {
                                var recivedData = JSON.parse(data.d);
                                $.each(recivedData.rows, function (key, value) {
                                    grid.jqGrid('addRowData', key, value);
                                });
                                grid.trigger('reloadGrid');
                            }
                        },
                        error: function (data, textStatus) {
                            alert('An error has occured retrieving data!');
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
```

The Ajax Call To fill The Grid

It's also my first post on Stack Overflow. hope i'v done it the right way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved

It seems that the method 'editGridRow' has a problem with 0 as value, I've added 1 to the key of the rows when creating the grid, making the row Id's start at 1 instead of 0. This now works.

```
...
//getting the data from the server

success: function (data, textStatus) {
                        if (textStatus == "success") {
                            var recivedData = JSON.parse(data.d);
                            $.each(recivedData.rows, function (key, value) {
                                grid.jqGrid('addRowData', 1+key, value);
                            });
                            grid.trigger('reloadGrid');
                        }
                    },
```